# UITextField Standard Style programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitextfield, uikit

When I create a `UITextField` using storyboard, it looks like the image below. However, when I create a `UITextField` programmatically it has absolutely no style. I know that I can apply custom styles to the text field, but is there an easy way to get this standard style when creating the text field programmatically?

[image: UITextField]

Comment: When you create UITextField using Storyboard it's automatically added to `view` with properties you have set in the attributes inspector. If you are creating it in code you need to add it's style from code also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
let t = UITextField()
t.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 20, width: self.view.frame.width - 20, height: 40)
t.layer.cornerRadius = 5
t.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
t.layer.borderWidth = 1
t.leftView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: t.frame.height))
t.leftViewMode = .always
t.rightView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: t.frame.height))
t.rightViewMode = .always
t.clearButtonMode = .whileEditing
self.view.addSubview(t)
```

**EDIT:**

Add this class below somewhere such that it is easily / globally accessible.

```
class StyledTextField: UITextField { 
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        self.layer.borderWidth = 1
        self.leftView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: t.frame.height))
        self.leftViewMode = .always
        self.rightView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: t.frame.height))
        self.rightViewMode = .always
        self.clearButtonMode = .whileEditing
    }
}
```

Then you can call this `UITextField` from where ever you want as follows

```
let t = StyledTextField()
t.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 20, width: self.view.frame.width - 20, height: 40)
self.view.addSubview(t)
```

**EDIT 2:**

Use `UIEdgeInsets` to get padding on all four sides.

```
class StyledTextField: UITextField { 
    let insetConstant = UIEdgeInsets(top: 4, left: 10, bottom: 4, right: 10)

    override func textRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(bounds, insetConstant)
    }

    override func editingRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(bounds, insetConstant)
    }

    override func placeholderRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(bounds, insetConstant)
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        self.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor(white: 2/3, alpha: 0.5).cgColor
        self.layer.borderWidth = 1
        self.clearButtonMode = .whileEditing
        self.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.decimalPad
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works! But isn't it possible to somehow create a UITextField that just uses the default style, without trying to reproduce it?

Comment: Hi @hoan, yes you can absolutely do that! The other answers people suggested allow you to do this easily. I will update mine to show you how

Comment: @hoan did you even read my answer, which was posted before this answer was edited to copy my answer and says the exact same thing plus more?

Comment: @RakeshaShastri I did, and your Subclassing explanation was great. I think the question I posed in the comments got misunderstood. I didn't want to know how to subclass the `UITextField`, because you already explained that. I wanted to know if there is a way to just get the default style provided by Apple, **without** creating any styling code myself. Because when using the Storyboard, you also don't have to style the `UITextField` in order to get the default style.

Comment: @hoan that is probably because it is set explicity when you create a an textfield in storyboard. And how does this answer answer your question?

Comment: @RakeshaShastri my initial question was about how to get/recreate the default styling of a `UITextField`, which is exactly what @AntersBear provided.

Comment: @hoan I see. I understand now. You wanted the exact different parameters which would reproduce the effect created by the storyboard? I would remove my downvote if the answer is slightly edited again because i can’t vote again unless it is edited. _My bad_ **Sorry**

Answer (score 2):

You can add **borderStyle** as **.roundedRect** and use **White background**. Something like this:

```
class MyCustmUITextField: UITextField { 
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.borderStyle = .roundedRect
        self.backgroundColor = .white
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a subclass from UITextField to serve as your custom text field.
Following this, you need only to instantiate your custom class and then you're good to go.
Something like this:

```
class MyCustmUITextField: UITextField { 
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black
        self.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)
        self.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        // then add whatever styles you wish
    } 
}
```

From there all you need is to create a new instance of MyCustomUITextField